# How to list and unlist Azure artifacts Package version based on testing using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, package, artifacts

I have setup a pipeline in azureDevops to publish new version of artefact, test this version and if it passes success criteria then list it otherwise unlist it. Kindly let me know how to list and unlist based on success criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this by setting a variable and based on results unlist a package by using below command using Nuget Custom task

delete $(Package)-Source $(SourcePath) -ApiKey $(APIKey)